# AWS Athena json_extract query from string field returns empty values

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table in athena with this structure

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `json_test`(
  `col0` string , 
  `col1` string , 
  `col2` string , 
  `col3` string , 
  `col4` string , 
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'='\;')
```

A Json String like this is stored in "col4":

```
{'email': 'test_email@test_email.com', 'name': 'Andrew', 'surname': 'Test Test'}
```

I´m trying to make a json_extract query:

```
SELECT json_extract(col4 , '$.email') as email FROM "default"."json_test"
```

But the query returns empty values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the json quoted? i only ask because i have seen the opencsvserde parse all the data and not spit erros, when you did a select col4 from json_test are you getting what you are expecting.

Comment: Json isn´t quoted. If I do a select * from json_test I get all rows correctly

Comment: if you do select col4 from json_test do you get the col with the json in it?

Comment: i only ask as i just ran something similar and i had problems.

Comment: yes, you are right, I do select col4 from json_test and I get the json string

Answer (score 12):

The JSON needs to use double quotes (`"`) for enclosing values.

Compare:

```
presto> SELECT json_extract('{"email": "test_email@test_email.com", "name": "Andrew"}' , '$.email');
            _col0
-----------------------------
 "test_email@test_email.com"
```

and

```
presto> SELECT json_extract('{''email'': ''test_email@test_email.com'', ''name'': ''Andrew''}', '$.email');
 _col0
-------
 NULL
```

(Note: `''` inside SQL varchar literal mean single `'` in the constructed value, so the literal here is the same format that in the question.)

If your string value is a "JSON with single quotes", you can try to fix it with [`replace(string, search, replace) → varchar`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the single quote char of the json string stored

```
{'email': 'test_email@test_email.com', 'name': 'Andrew', 'surname': 'Test Test'}
```

Changing to double quote

```
{"email": "test_email@test_email.com", "name": "Andrew", "surname": "Test Test"}
```

Athena Query works properly:

```
SELECT json_extract(col4 , '$.email') as email FROM "default"."json_test"
```

Comment: please mark @Piotr Findeisen answer as correct then, since he was the one who provided you with the answer first